# How to use ISAPI WebService

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, isapi

I have created an SOAP WebService as an ISAPI DLL ( with Delphi XE6 ) , but when i upload it on my host and when i try to execute it , noyhing happens !

I have tested my webservice as an stand alone application but know i converted it to an ISAPI DLL and I want to use it in my host

for example when i upload it in "vault-script/WebService" folder and when I type this address :

"http://example.com/vault_scripts/Web_Service/ISAPI.dll"

OR

"http://example.com/vault_scripts/Web_Service/ISAPI.dll?wsdl/INPG_WService"

Browser says "Not Found !"

How I should use this webService ?!

In other words I want to get WSDL XML address to import it in my client application !

I`m Using Delphi XE6 and my host is Windows with IIS 7.5

thanks

Comment: Delphi XE6 is compiled in win32. The IIS7.5 is this win32 or win64?

Comment: I have created both Win32 and Win64 DLL and Browser shows "Not Found" for both

Comment: Did you follow these steps http://chee-yang.blogspot.be/2009/10/configure-windows-7-iis7-for-isapi-dll.html

Comment: But I want to upload it on my host , not in my windows IIS directory !!

Comment: There is IIS on your host?

Comment: Dear Friend , I want to Upload this ISAPI WebService on a Host that is on a server with Windows Server 2008 and have IIS 7.5 , I`m not the server admin !!! , I cant set any configuration on server , there is just Plesk Panel ! and i cant find any configuration about ISAPI ! , I think I should call server admins , any Idea ?!

Comment: First thing to check is of the ISAPI extensions and filter are installed on the host IIS 7.5. If you don't have the rights ask it to the server admin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the ISAPI filters rule in IIS under "ISAPI Filters"  option. You will need to allow the particular extension in IIS. You can enable the extension under "Request Filtering".

Comment: thanks , how should I do that ? , Filters are in Server settings ? , I cant find them !